# How to avoid printing quotation marks in cat <<

Tags: bash, heredoc

I am trying to generate a file given a template with this code in `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

#define parameters which are passed in.
ID=$1
DIRECTORY=$2

#define the template.
cat  <<EOF
./pgap.py -D singularity -r -o $DIRECTORY/$ID $DIRECTORY/$ID'_input.yaml'
```

I used `'` in the last line to avoid the text trailing the `$ID` variable to be mixed with it. But when running the code prints both `'`.
In other words, when I run:

```
bash test.sh id dir
```

I get

```
./pgap.py -D singularity -r -o dir/id dir/id'_input.yaml'
```

, but I'd like to get:

```
./pgap.py -D singularity -r -o dir/id dir/id_input.yaml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$DIRECTORY/$ID'_input.yaml'
```

with

```
$DIRECTORY/${ID}_input.yaml
```

Comment: Or `'$DIRECTORY/${ID}_input.yaml'`, since quotes aren't parsed/respected in here-documents. This will put the single-quotes literally in the resulting document, which (since it looks like that is a shell script) is probably what you actually want.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Thank you for pointing this out. I have corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you're trying to do with the single quotes by enclosing the variable name in curly braces, i.e. `$DIRECTORY/${ID}_input.yaml`